# How to get parameters in different groups in openapi-generator

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I am new to [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator).

Part of my yaml file is like below. in the generator (in the moustache file) I am able to get all parameters by using `allParams` and it will return

```
ChannelTimezoneNameHeader,
LanguageHeader,

goalId,
customerId
```

My question is how can I get first category of parameters and second category separately, not combined together?

```
/accounts/customer/{customerId}/goals/{goalId}/transactions:
      x-swagger-router-controller: "GoalsController"
      parameters:
        -
          $ref: "#/parameters/ChannelTimezoneNameHeader"
        -
          $ref: "#/parameters/LanguageHeader"
      get:
        tags:
          - "goals"
        summary: "get goal transactions for a customer account"
        description: ""
        operationId: "getGoalTransactions"
        security:
          -
            AuthorizationHeader: []
            XIdTokenHeader: []
        parameters:
          -
            name: "goalId"
            in: "path"
            description: "goalId"
            required: true
            type: "string"
          -
            name: "customerId"
            in: "path"
            description: "customerId"
            required: true
            type: "string"
        responses:
          200:
            description: "successful operation"
            schema:
              $ref: "#/definitions/TransactionListGoal"
          400:
            description: "Bad Request"
            schema:
              $ref: "#/definitions/ChannelApiError"
          500:
            description: "Server error"
            schema:
              $ref: "#/definitions/ChannelApiError"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need to get path-level parameters separately from operation-level parameters? Path-level parameters (in your example - ChannelTimezoneNameHeader and LanguageHeader) propagate to each operation under that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the following mustache tags:

```
{{#queryParams}} ... {{/queryParams}}

{{#formParams}} ... {{/formParams}}

{{#headerParams}} ... {{/headerParams}}

{{#pathParams}} ... {{/pathParams}}

{{#bodyParams}} ... {{/bodyParams}}
```